# Targeting the HTML ID of Node when User scrolls to it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I recently asked about it, but seems like the previous answer wasn't about what I was looking for. If I have some code like this:

```
<br><br><br>...Lots of BRs...<br><br><br>
<div id="thetargetone"></div><div id="show"></div>
<br><br><br>...Lots of BRs...<br><br><br>
<div id="thetargettwo"></div><div id="show"></div>
<br><br><br>...Lots of BRs...<br><br><br>
<div id="thetargetthree"></div><div id="show"></div>
<br><br><br>...Lots of BRs...<br><br><br>
//and so on...
```

And what I want is, when user scrolls(or pressing "space" or in other way) comes to this specific IDs (`id=thetargetone` or `thetargettwo` etc) I will target them with JavaScript code to manipulate the properties. For example, if user scrolls to `id="thetargetone"` JavaScript will fire opacity of the `id="thetargetone"`. Is this possible to do with only JavaScript? If so, how can I do this, please?

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to use Bootstrap's plugin [Scrollspy](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp). You can find documentation on Bootstrap's page [there](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). It's very simple to use:

```
$('#myScrollspy').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure Javascript function:

```
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName("target");
var theTarget = targets[0];

window.findTarget = function() {
    var closest = 10000000;
    for(var i=0; i<targets.length; i++) {
        var scrolled = document.body.scrollTop;
        var fromTop = targets[i].offsetTop;

        //console.log(Math.abs(fromTop - scrolled) + " | " + i + " | " + scrolled + " | " + closest);
        if(Math.abs(fromTop - scrolled) < closest) {
            closest = Math.abs(fromTop - scrolled);
            theTarget = targets[i];
            //console.log(closest + " | " + i);
        }
    }
    console.log(theTarget.id);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", findTarget);
```

- Set an arbitrary large number
- Calculate the window scroll position
- Calculate all the element's position from the top
- Get the smallest number and store the corresponding reference (`theTarget`)

Once you get the reference you would say for example:

```
theTarget.style.display = "none";
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vr69ngcr/1/

**There are console logs that show the `id` of the closest target changing as you scroll**

Comment: Thank you. But can you please explain a little bit how to use this? As I understand, instead of targeting the specific `id`s, you're targeting class `target` and then look for the nearest of this class. If so, how can I `display:none;` the `id="thetargetone"` for example if it's the nearest `target`?

Comment: I have made an example in the updated fiddle, watch the console logs. After 5 seconds the closest target will disappear.

Comment: Can you please show me how to make `display: none` for each nearest id is user on? because I can't make it work... it fires only once :/

Comment: Yes, tried exactly like you said my self - didn't work. Also in your last example - https://jsfiddle.net/vr69ngcr/2/ - it didn't work. It fires only once and set `display:none;` only for the `thetargetone`

Comment: I can only help you so much, I have provided a valid working example. Please explore more and come back.